# How to name a new dataframe based on input character value

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I am trying to get input from a user to create the name of a new data frame. e.g

```
number <- readline(prompt = "what is your number:")
```

Which creates a character string with one entry, e.g number: "4"

Now i want to create a dataframe named after the character inputted, and subset some other information based on that number from another table, for example:

```
number_4 <- subset(df, df$NO=="4")
```

As i might be doing hundreds of these i do not want to have to manually name each dataframe, is there a way to use the character to name a dataframe?

Comment: Do not do this. It's a design mistake to give users any power over how objects are named internally. It makes everything more difficult and offers absolutely no advantage.

Comment: Thanks, but I am the user! I want to pull and name data frames just by typing in a number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `assign` function

```
assign(paste0("number_", number), subset(df, NO == number))
```